# Simplifying Trig Identity

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation I have been given to solve, I know how to start but I do not know what to do after I use the Trig Identities. Any help?

Here is what I was given
$$
\frac{\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B)}{\sin A \sin B}
$$
I got to this step
$$
\frac{\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B + \cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B}{\sin A\sin B}
$$
What do I do next to simplify?

Comment: $\sin a\sin b-\sin a\sin b=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B) & = \cos(A) \cos(B) - \sin(A) \sin(B) + \cos(A) \cos(B) + \sin(A) \sin(B)\\
& = 2 \cos(A) \cos(B)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B)}{\sin(A) \sin(B)} = 2 \cot(A) \cot(B)$$